# macOS Big Sur - Where is the icon file (.icns) for System Preferences.app?

Tags: icon, big-sur

On macOS Big Sur, I believe this is the location for the Sys Prefs app: `/System/Applications/System Preferences.app`, but I cannot find a .icns icon file for the app anywhere in this directory. So where is the icon file for Sys Prefs app?

Command I use to find .icns file in the current directory (`fd` can be installed with `brew`):

```
fd -e icns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **System Preferences** icon...

In **macOS Catalina** the **System Preferences** icon, **PrefApp.icns**, is located at:

```
/System/Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/Resources/PrefApp.icns
```

However, in **macOS Big Sur** it is now included in its **Assets.car** *file*:

```
/System/Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/Resources/Assets.car
```

In **Finder**, you can *right-click* on the *application bundle* and select **Show Package Contents** to navigate to these *files*, or copy them using **Terminal**.

The image below is a *third-party utility* called [**Asset Catalog Tinkerer**](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer), to which I have no affiliation. You can use it to view the contents and drag and drop out of it the image you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/System/Applications/`, right click System Preferences, click `Get info`, and select the icon at the top. Press `Command+C`, then open preview and press `Command+N` to make a new file from your clipboard. Now save the file as an `icns`.

Comment: There is no "icns" option when saving.